# How to deregister global Font Awesome enqueued by plugins?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, font-awesome

If I already enqueue Font Awesome in my WordPress theme, how do I deregister Font Awesome enqueued by other plugins so that my theme always enqueue Font Awesome just once?

In other words, if I use 3 plugins that uses Font Awesome, I wouldn't like to enqueue Font Awesome by 3 times but only once.

The solution I have in mind is something like this (pseudo code):

```
// check css
if ('font-family') = 'FontAwesome' {
      // dequeue FontAwesome used by plugins
      wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin-font-awesome' );
      // add the theme version
      wp_enqueue_style ('font-awesome', $url)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dequeue a style, for do that you can use [wp_dequeue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) or [wp_deregister_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style)

To use both of them, first you need to find the handler of the script.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-font-awesome', plugins_url('my-plugin/font-awesome.css') );
```

and you need to deregister or dequeue it

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_fontawesome_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_fontawesome_deregister_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'my-plugin-font-awesome' );
}
```

or

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_fontawesome_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_fontawesome_deregister_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'my-plugin-font-awesome' );
}
```

OBS: the priority must be higher than the plugin's wp_enqueue_scripts()

---

**Question Modified**

In that case I think you can try to check for `global $wp_styles;` it's an object $wp_styles->registered is an array with all registered styles, you could do a foreach on it, checking with a regex on both **handle** and **src** for font-awesome (and some variants) and dequeue that.

I think it should work, I didn't test it.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_automatically_dequeue_scripts', 110 );

function my_automatically_dequeue_scripts() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $stylesheets = $wp_styles->registered;
    foreach ( $stylesheets as stylesheet ) {
        if( checkwithregex stylesheet['handle'] and stylesheet['src'] )
            wp_dequeue_style( 'stylesheet["handle"]' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't quite clear. I know how to deregister a style. My question was how to do this for any future plugins used by a public theme, without manually find the handle and add a function for every plugin that enqueue the Font Awesome.  I updated the question body to be more clear.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Alexan I think it's a good start, I didn't test it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Marcos Rodrigues! Yes, it's a good start here, but I still don't feel comfortable with regex so I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895007/how-to-dequeue-a-wordpress-style-using-regex) :)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not good with regex, so I can't help you with that.
Link the question with my answer it would be a good practice. Sorry can't help any further.

Comment: Thanks anyway @Marcos Rodrigues!