# How to dequeue a WordPress style using regex?

Tags: css, regex, wordpress, font-awesome

I need to check with **regex** on both **handle** and **src** for *font-awesome* (and some variants) expression and dequeue that style.

I need this function to dequeue all Font Awesome stylesheets generated by plugins, since the theme already uses this font.

The solution I have in mind is something like this (pseudo code):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_automatically_dequeue_scripts', 110 );

function my_automatically_dequeue_scripts() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $stylesheets = $wp_styles->registered;
    foreach ( $stylesheets as $stylesheet ) {
        if( check_with_regex $stylesheet['handle'] and $stylesheet['src'] )
            wp_dequeue_style( 'stylesheet["handle"]' );
    }
}
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean "all FA stylesheets"? I can only [see one](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/css)...

Comment: @brasofolio, if you use a theme that use Font Awesome and you also have 2 active plugins (e.g. social icons, menu icons) that both load Font Awesome too, you will end up with 3 font-awesome.css stylesheets loaded. But you only need one, right? However, I think I found a [fix](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dequeue-font-awesome/).